# How to fix 'args is not defined' error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

by wanting to create a musical bot, I quickly noticed by ending coded that the bot does not start for an error that is indicated below the code. Thank you for enlightening me as possible.

Thanks to help me

```
switch (args[0].tolowerCase()) {
  case "play":
    if (!args[1]) {
      message.channel.send("Indiquez le __lien__ s'il vous plaît !");
      return; 
   }

if(!message.member.voiceChannel) {
  message.channel.send("Vous devez vous trouvez dans un salon **vocal** 
!");
  return;     

    }

    if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
      queue : []
    }

   var server = servers[message.guild.id]

    server.queue.push(args[1]);

    if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) 
message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection) {
  play(connection, message);
    })
    break;
  case "skip" :
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

    if (server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
    break;
  case "stop" :
    var servers = servers[message.guild.id];

    if (message.guild.voiceConnection) 
    message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect();
        break;
  default:
    message.channel.send("La commande saisie est invalide !");
}
```

This is the console log.

```
ReferenceError: args is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Nolosha 
 Bot\index.js:170:1)
```

Comment: On the first line of the code from your snippet you use `args[0]`. Where have you defined the args variable?

Comment: No, I haven't defined the args variable. How How should I define it?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

The error you receive is saying that you haven't declared the variable `args`, but you're trying to use it anyway. Make sure that you have set `args` prior to using it.

```js
const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
```

This code takes the message content, removes any whitespace on the beginning or end, and then splits it up into pieces by spaces, returning an array. Keep in mind that it can't be redefined within the same block because it's a [constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Comment: Thanks. I  inserted the command, and now the error is not the same:ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Nolosha Bot\index.js:6:14)

Comment: Are you within a `message` event? I've used `message` as the parameter's name, but you might be using something different.

Comment: I try in another folder

Comment: What's the rest of the line for `client.on('message', ` (or `bot`)?

Comment: For the exact code above, it must be inside of your client's `message` event (or where a message is accessible), and the message must be stored in `message`.

Comment: check my other answer plz

Comment: As I said, "it must be inside of your client's `message` event." It isn't in the code you've shown.

Comment: And how to fix that?

Comment: You might want to check the example provided under "Example Usage" [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

Comment: Wait. I test `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);` and now the error is : `TypeError: args[0].tolowerCase is not a function` 
What should I do ?

Comment: `args[0].toLowerCase()`

Comment: I add uppercase on the L, but the error message continue

Comment: Ok ok, I try a new command `var args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).splith("%20");` And This makes the "message" still not defined. The console marks me that the problem comes from the word "message" of the command which I have just indicated you

Comment: Created a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194294/discussion-from-how-to-fix-args-is-not-defined-error-in-node-js) to help you. Comments aren't for extended discussion.

Comment: I can't, I haven't 20 reputation point. Do you have a discord account ?